# If else within switch error

Tags: php

Hello I am using this line of code:

```
     case "3rd Year":
                 $lbl="4th Year";
**This is the line**       if( $get_display->gpa => "88" ) {
                                $section_name = 'A';
                            }
                            elseif( $get_display->gpa => "80" ) {
                                $section_name = 'B';
                            }
                            elseif( $get_display->gpa => "75" ) {
                                $section_name = 'C';                      
                            }
                 break;
```

Currently Spatting this line of error:
Would appreciate any help.

```
     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\enrollpage.php on line 293
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace `=>` by `>=`

Answer (score 1):

You are either trying to check for greater than or equal to which should use:

```
if( $get_display->gpa >= "88" )
```

or you have missed the actual comparison in your if statement if it is an array:

```
if( $get_display->gpa['88'] == "something" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the operators! You want to use >=